# ?^^ used in in Angular JS 1.x Component

Tags: angularjs

I am working on Angular JS 1.x (I know the FW is outdated :)) where in I noted the following convention to be used much in component configuration.

```
require: {
      componentContoller1: '^componentContoller1',
    },
```

I understand that we asking angular to get componentContoller1's controller instantiated and bind it to a property in current component, but I also noticed following convention like

```
require: {
          componentContoller1: '?^^componentContoller1',
        },
```

Can someone tell me what is the difference here using `?^^`, I tried google and angular doc but could not get a clarity. Any help great and thanks.

Complete configuration or set up will be like

```
angular.module('moduleName').component('componentName',{
templateUrl: "path to template",
require: {
          componentContoller1: '?^^componentContoller1',
         },
controller(){ //code }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-)

- **(no prefix)** - Locate the required controller on the current element.
  Throw an error if not found.
- **?** - Attempt to locate the required controller or pass null to the link fn if not found.
- **^** - Locate the required controller by searching **the element and its parents**. Throw an error if not found.
- **^^** - Locate the required controller by searching **the element's parents**. Throw an error if not found.
- **?^** - Attempt to locate the required controller by searching **the element and its parents** or pass null to the link fn if not found.
- **?^^** - Attempt to locate the required controller by searching **the element's parents**, or pass null to the link fn if not found.